react-i18next Uncaught Error: A component suspended while responding to synchronous input
I tried to install react-i18next and I followed the official documentation. There's a point, where it says import the i18n.js in the index.js file.
import './i18n'
However after I import the i18n.js, I get the following errors and all the pages crash:
Uncaught Error: A component suspended while responding to synchronous input. This will cause the UI to be replaced with a loading indicator. To fix, updates that suspend should be wrapped with startTransition.

I tried to check the full documentation, but I haven't find any solution to the problem and haven't find any mention what can cause this error.

I'm making a lot of assumptions here since this question has very little context, but considering I just spent all day working from the opposite direction I figured I would share in case your issue is similar.
if you're following the implementation via i18n docs your i18n file looks something like this
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import resourcesToBackend from 'i18next-resources-to-backend';

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .use(resourcesToBackend((language, namespace) => import(`./public/locales/${language}/${namespace}.json`)))
  .init({
    lng: "en-US", // if you're using a language detector, do not define the lng option
    fallbackLng: ["en-US", "en", "fr"],

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false // react already safes from xss => https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation#unescape
    }
  });

export default i18n;

Which works fine most of the time, unless there are pages that start attempting to render and re-render while i18n is still getting its resources. Easy fix, just wait for i18n to finish before doing anything else.
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import resourcesToBackend from 'i18next-resources-to-backend';

const languageInit = i18n
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .use(resourcesToBackend((language, namespace) => import(`./public/locales/${language}/${namespace}.json`)))
  .init({
    lng: "en-US", // if you're using a language detector, do not define the lng option
    fallbackLng: ["en-US", "en", "fr"],

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false // react already safes from xss => https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation#unescape
    }
  });

  export default languageInit;

Now wherever you import you can just wrap it.
languageInit.then(()=>{
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={<Loading />} persistor={persistor}>
          <Router/>
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
})

